# How do you ensure that an inherited static field always takes its value from the subclass and not the base class?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I'm trying to put the `hello` method in the base class `A` and I want it to display the value of `x` that is set in the subclass.

The `hello` method is never called by an instance of `A` - this class is a pure base class and is never instantiated.

The `x` variable is a classifier to notate where the hello method is being called from (this value is actually persisted to the database);

If `hello` is called in the subclass, how do you ensure that the value of `x` is the value set in the subclass?

```
public class A{

  protected static String x = "A";

  public void hello(){
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}

public class B extends A{

  protected static String x = "B";

  //...
  hello();
}

public class C extends A{

  protected static String x = "C";

  //...
  hello();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You're trying to get polymorphic behaviour from fields, but they simply don't behave polymorphically. The `x` in `hello()` is bound at compile-time to the field in `A`.

If you want polymorphic behaviour, you'll need to introduce a non-final (possibly abstract) method and override it in each subclass. Then `hello()` can call this method, and polymorphism will ensure that the right override is called. Of course, `hello()` can't be a *static* method as polymorphism doesn't apply to static methods either... the target of the method invocation (the object you call it on) will determine the implementation used.

Comment: "introduce a virtual method" - Too much C# lately? `;)`

Comment: virtual method == non static/instance method?

Comment: @jjnguy: I still think of them as virtual methods - it's just that that's the default.

Comment: @Nivas: No, virtual method == method called virtually, i.e. with polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: @jjnguy: Yes, I know that. But it can't be a static method or a non-final one. The point is that it has to be something which will exhibit polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: @Jon, when writing Java code, you you often make your methods final?

Comment: @jjnguy: I do when I'm bothered - usually I don't, just through laziness. I agree with Josh Bloch that you should design for inheritance or prohibit it - I just fail to remember to make things final too often :(

Answer (score 2):

I would make a few changes:

First, make class `A` `abstract`.  This will ensure that it is never instantiated.

Second, I would change your `protected` `static` variable to an abstract method in class `A`.

So, you would have:

```
protected String x();
```

in class `A`.  And then you would be forced to implement it in the subclasses:

```
@Overrides
protected String x() {
   return "B";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override a static variable, actually you cannot override any variables. Override is for methods, hiding is for variables.

To do what you are looking to do (I think), in your class constructors, set the private variable (get rid of the static) to "A", "B", "C". Get rid of the strings in class B and C.